# Pyspark Spark Session created out of main generate deadlock

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, deadlock

I'm working on an app pyspark which use hive table. I create an spark session into my main but in an other file, i have to create a new one. All the operation is good in the new file but when i have to comeback to the next operation from my main file, it is stuck like a deadlock on this instruction:

```
self.spark.table(self.table_to_write).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(
                self.destination, mode="overwrite"
```

I get the sparksession with these lines:

`spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()`

Maybe call a sparksession into a spark session generate this error?

Thank you guys

I try to recreate a new sparkession with these ligne.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(
    "X"
).getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(
    os.getenv("CHECKPOINTS_DIR", "/tmp/checkpoints")
)
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("src.zip")
```

Comment: How does the error message look like?

Comment: There is no error message.

Comment: It is stuck at this instruction self.spark.table(self.table_to_write).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(
                self.destination, mode="overwrite"